# How to handle sqlite exceptions in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am preparing a simple user registration application. The database contains only two fields, username and password where username is the primary key. When I try to enter a duplicate a record, it throws an exception (as expected). I want to show a custom message saying "User already exists". This is my code:

```
public boolean addUser(UserDetails user) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("USERNAME", user.getUserId());
    values.put("PASSWORD", user.getPassword());

    try {
        db.insert("USERNAME_PASSWORD", null, values);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
    db.close();
    return true;
}


//In the class from which I am calling this method:
    boolean isAdded = util.addUser(user);
        if (!isAdded) {
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "Username alread exists! Try with another user name.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

In the logcat, I see the exception details. I want to provide some kind of error message to the user, but the function is always returning `true`. Please suggest a way to do this.

Comment: What is the schema for the `USERNAME_PASSWORD` table? Is the `USERNAME` column declared as the primary key or as `UNIQUE`?

Comment: @MonadNewb: The username column is a primary key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `insertOrThrow()` to make insert throw an exception for you to catch

But in my opinion going with ccheneson's solution is better practice than catching an exception

Comment: Neither I am using a log nor dialog. I am using a Toast!

Answer (score 0):

Create a new method `getUser(String userId)` and call it from your `addUser` method.

If `getUser` returns something, then from your `addUser` method,`return true`;

Comment: It's a simple select query, it should be fast